# Deleted a file that I need for the mission "Through the Spyglass"

Tags: hacknet

I have made really good progress on Hacknet, but I am at the mission "Through the Spyglass" for CSEC. I accidentally deleted (because I thought they were logs) all the files in the /WORKLOGS folder. I didn't know that the password required to end the mission was in the files I deleted.

Is there any other way to retrieve the password?

Answer (score 2):

go to Hacknet\Content\Missions\MainHub\DecypherSet\DECHeadMission02.xml

Open the file. Now you can see the password at line four "goal target= "PASSWORD"

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to retrieve the password?

No, unless you count external methods, such as checking the game files or searching on the Internet. However, if you didn't save your session, you can simply exit the game (with <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> or the cross in the top left), start it again, and start over.

If you already saved your session, you need to start over. Alternatively, search the Hacknet folder (on your actual PC) for the string "WORKLOGS". There should be only five matches throughout all files.

Luckily, this password is a static one, so you can simply look check the following spoiler if you don't want to be bothered with another scavenger hunt:

> beepbeep